# What is the probability of having both girls given that at least one of them is girl?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm reading the textbook entitled Harvard Statistics by Joseph K. Blitskein. In conditional probability context, I'm a little bit confused of calculating the intersection of event A and B $P(A\cap B)$. The problem is given below;

> Example 2.2.5 (Elder is a girl vs. at least one girl). A family has two children, and it is known that at least one is a girl. What is the probability that both are girls, given this information? What if it is known that the elder child is a girl?

For the solution (based on textbook):

First, let the following events equal to A and B (just to keep it short):

A = event of having both girls, B = event of at least one girl

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}=\frac{1/4}{3/4}=1/3$$

Intuitively, the answer is correct but I was wondering on why $P(A∩B)=1/4$. Since $P(A∩B)=P(A)P(B)$, which in this case $P(A)=1/4$ and $P(B)=3/4$. Just to give you a reference, the possible combinations of having two children are ${\{GG, BG, GB, BB}\}$.

Anyone can shed me a light regarding with my problem?

Comment: Probabilty both girls and probability at least one girl are not independent.  It is *impossible* to have two girls if there is not at least one girl and if you have two girls it is impossible *not* to have at least one girl.  Common sense: $A\subset B$ and   $A\cap B = A$ and $P(A\cap B) = P(A)$

Comment: Thing to realize is when $A \subset B$ then $A\cap B = A$ and $P(A\cap B) = P(A)$.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1266043/boy-and-girl-paradox-is-driving-me-crazy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ should be defined as events and not probabilities. $A$ is the event of having both girls and $B$ is the event of having *at least* one girl. By definition, you can see that they are not independent events. Hence $P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)$ does not hold. When we estimate $P(A,B)$, only one combination works $(GG)$ out of the four possible combinations. Hence the probability of both having both girls and having at least one girl is $P(A,B)=1/4$.

Comment: Oh I see! thanks for the correction. I misunderstood the definition of $P(A,B)$ that's the reason why I'm having a trouble on calculating the intersection of two events. This rule $P(A,B) =  P(A)P(B)$ is only applicable for dependent events?

Comment: @King $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$ only for ***in***dependent events.

Comment: Thanks I got it now :) sorry for noob question.